# Azure Machine Learning Studio Designer Error: code_expired

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to register a data set via the Azure Machine Learning Studio designer but keep getting an error. Here is my code, used in a "Execute Python Script" module:

```
import pandas as pd
from azureml.core.dataset import Dataset
from azureml.core import Workspace

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    ws = Workspace.get(name = <my_workspace_name>, subscription_id = <my_id>, resource_group = <my_RG>)
    ds = Dataset.from_pandas_dataframe(dataframe1)
    ds.register(workspace = ws,
                name = "data set name",
                description = "example description",
                create_new_version = True)
    return dataframe1,
```

But I get the following error in the Workspace.get line:

```
Authentication Exception: Unknown error occurred during authentication. Error detail: Unexpected polling state code_expired.
```

Since I am inside the workspace and in the designer, I do not usually need to do any kind of authentication (or even reference the workspace). Can anybody offer some direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're inside a "Execute Python Script" module or `PythonScriptStep`, the authentication for fetching the workspace is already done for you (unless you're trying to authenticate to different Azure ML workspace.

```py
from azureml.core import Run
run = Run.get_context()

ws = run.experiment.workspace
```

You should be able to use that `ws` object to register a Dataset.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, although I got a different error; it said that "create_new_version" was an unexpected keyword argument. If I remove the argument, I get a different error: "Local data source path not supported for this operation." I do need it to create new versions if a previous version already exists, so I am trying to figure this out and will post a separate question if I can't. Thanks again!

Comment: Still no luck, so I will post a separate question as soon as possible. Thanks!